# Dynamic iframe in a Pop up Window

Tags: javascript

I am trying to achieve 2 things with the href links below. First, I would like to fire-up a pop up window. Done. Next, I would like that pop up window to display an iframe. This was easily accomplished as well **until** I realized I needed to pass the href link text as a parameter in my iframe src.

So for example, the iframe wont load in my pop up window unless its `src="http://localhost:8080/test/document.html?OnSale"`

I cannot figure out why the `document.write` in the body of my html page won't print out the dynamic iframe Im trying to create with my foo() function in the href links...

```
<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#"  onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">
            <img align="right" src="http://localhost:8080/test/img/close_img.png">
        </a>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function foo(obj)
    {
        test1 = "http://localhost:8080/test/document.html?"+obj.text; 
        document.write('<iframe height="450"  allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;" src="'+test1+'" type= "text/javascript"></iframe>');
    } 
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv');foo(this);">OnSale</a>
```

**EDIT:**
Here is my full html page. Everything is running locally on tomcat7 w/ win7 and firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/css-pop.js"></script>
    <link href="http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#"  onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">
        <img align="right" src="http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/x.png">
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo(obj){
            test1 = "http://localhost:8080/test/document.html?"+obj.innerHTML;
            document.write('<iframe height="450"  allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;" src="'+test1+'" type= "text/javascript"></iframe>');

        }
    </script>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv');foo(this);">OnSale</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`text` is not a standard for all browsers, try `innerHTML` instead of that,

```
function foo(obj){
     test1 = "http://localhost:8080/test/document.html?"+obj.innerHTML; 
     document.write('<iframe height="450"  allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;" src="'+test1+'" type= "text/javascript"></iframe>');
}
```

**UPDATED after you had shared your whole code,**

As I understand you want to open a popup window, and show an dynamically created iframe in it. But document.write works for your current window. So you have to handle your popup window at first. then change content of that.

try this,

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/css-pop.js"></script>
<link href="http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>


<div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
        <a href="#"  onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">
            <img align="right" src="http://localhost:8080/test/css-popup/x.png">
        </a>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var popUpWindow;
    function popup(n) {
       popUpWindow = window.open(n);
    }
                function foo(obj){
                test1 = "http://localhost:8080/test/document.html?"+obj.innerHTML; 
                popUpWindow.document.write('<iframe height="450" allowTransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" style="width:100%;" src="'+test1+'" type= "text/javascript"></iframe>');

                } 
        </script>
</div>

        <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv');foo(this);">OnSale</a>

</body>
</html>​
```

And [here is working live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/U8wCc/1/)

Comment: I appreciate the help ocanal. innerHTML didn't do it either, but thats good to learn about text not being standard

Comment: ocanal,thank you! this opens the iframe perfectly but it opens as a new tab in firefox not a pop-up window. Is there any way the window.open(n) can be a pop up instead of new tab?

Comment: @Chris, yes it can be a pop up if you set height and weight attribute for new window, something like -> `window.open("",n, "height=500,width=500")`