# Open iframe link in pop up on click

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a link which opens an iframe.

```
<a href"https://www.suse.com/common/inc/feedback_overlay.html?iframe=true">Test</a>
```

I want to open this link (iframe) in pop up if anyone clicks on a link.

Please help.

Comment: You need to add a lightbox around your link, or code your own version

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic iframe in a Pop up Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474313/dynamic-iframe-in-a-pop-up-window)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force different links to open in a new Pop-up window every time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373892/force-different-links-to-open-in-a-new-pop-up-window-every-time)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function OpenInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank', 'height=500,width=500');
}
```

```html
<a href"#" onClick="OpenInNewTab('https://www.suse.com/common/inc/feedback_overlay.html?iframe=true');">Test</a>
```